# how to delete the nodes having a specific entity reference but not the parent

Tags: 7, views

I have a content type "students" and another "courses".
Student nodes are created with an entity reference to a course node.

I need to delete all students of "couses123" in a quick way.
How can I make a view which has a dropdown of all course names and when selected it shows list of all students.

From there, I can use the [VBO](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) to show a checkbox next to them for selection and deletion .

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this a one-time need, you could build a custom query DB query if you wanted to go the developer route. However, if this is an ongoing need you're better off with the site builder route you've hinted at in your question.

In your case, you want to a create a node view filtered by content type *Students*. Add a **Entity Reference: Referenced Entity** for the field that contains your references to *Courses*. The last step is to add an exposed filter for the same *Courses* field making sure enable relationship that you added; that will present a select list of referenced Courses from which you can filter down the *Students* and present your VBO delete widget.